# Office 365 About me Delve

Tags: office-365

I've been using Office 365(E3) for a while now.When I navigate to 'About Me' I'm redirected to the My Sites.

Is it possible to change the My Sites to the Delve profile?

Comment: Asking that myself. In my company it redirects to delve. But on my private tenant I always get to the mysite!